# What happens when an invisible creature interacts with an illusion?

Tags: dnd-5e, illusion, invisibility

What happens when an invisible creature physically interacts with a minor illusion from the perspective of that creature and from the perspective of another creature that is looking at the illusion at the time?

Would it be revealed as an illusion to other creatures?

RAW, any physical interaction reveals it to be an illusion, but it doesn't say to who specifically: notice the text uses "if a creature" not "if the creature".

On this basis, it would seem even interactions from invisible creatures may make it clear to other creatures that it's an illusion (perhaps because the illusion ripples on the surface). It seems to be missing something like, "if a creature sees itself or another creature physically interact with an illusion then..."

Answer (score 8):

The description of [Minor Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) states:

> Physical interaction with the image reveals it to be an illusion, because things can pass through it.
>
> If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the illusion becomes faint **to the creature**.

The description of [Programmed Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/programmed-illusion) states:

> Physical interaction with the image reveals it to be an illusion, because things can pass through it. [...] If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the creature can see through the image, and any noise it makes sounds hollow **to the creature**.

Invisibility doesn't change the outcome of discerning the nature of an illusion, and the illusion is only changed for the creature that interacted with it since he's invisible and no one else could witness the interaction and discern the illusion for what it is.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, RAW, any physical interaction reveals it to be an illusion, but it doesn't say to who specifically, notice the text uses "if a creature" not "if the creature". On this basis, it would seem even interactions from invisible creatures may make it clear to other creatures that it's an illusion (perhaps because the illusion ripples on the surface).

It seems to be missing something like, "if a creature sees itself or another creature physically interact with an illusion then..."

Comment: @Jinglesting Your interpretation isn't right, but that's likely because I didn't paste the entire spell effect.  Follow the links for the full spell effect to see what "a creature" means in a larger context.

Comment: Your last sentence is not quite right. The illusion is changed for any creature that discern the illusion for what it is; anyone that witness the weird interaction will also realize the illusion. This, however, is irrelevant in this case - the 'interactor' is invisible, thus the interaction is also imperceptible to others, but I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @Vylix Good point.  I expanded my last sentence to include that info.

Comment: @Vylix how do we know the interactions are invisible? Is this an assumption on the basis that the creature is invisible?